# Eigenfunction Expansion for Simple Nonhomogenous PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

How do I go about finding an eigenfunction expansion for the following equation:

$$ u'' = f(x)$$ where: $$ u'(0) = \alpha \quad u'(1) = \beta$$

What about the case when $f(x) = C$ a constant?

Edit:

Okay, so I found the eigenfunction:

$$ \phi - \lambda \phi = 0 $$
$$ \rightarrow r^{2} - \lambda = 0 \Rightarrow r = \{ \lambda^{0.5}, -\lambda^{0.5} \}$$

So our general solution is:

$$ \phi = A e^{\sqrt{ \lambda}x} + B e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$$

But, 1. How do I find A and B? and 2. How do I write the eigenfunction expansion? What does that even mean?

Edit: Related, but unsatisfactory [Eigenfunction expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560625/eigenfunction-expansion?rq=1)